# What can be done with a Haskell monad that cannot be done with a Lisp macro, and vice-versa?

Tags: haskell, macros, lisp, monads

My current understanding is that macros can implement any imaginable concept, including monads, because they "have the compiler at hands". Is this true? For example, I have came across this [link](https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-monad-macros/monad-macros.htm)

Please, give me facts and examples, no passionate answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's kind of an odd comparison. It's a bit like asking "what can a petrol car do that a diesel generator cannot?" Er, well, those aren't really the same class of thing...

Lisp macros [which I know almost nothing about] allow you to do compile-time meta-programming. You can use that to achieve all sorts of useful things, from eliminating a bit of boilerplate code to virtually defining an entire new programming language.

Haskell monads are a useful way to structure certain kinds of computations. They make it easy to do certain things which are otherwise a bit tedious. (E.g., checking the result of each and every function to make sure it succeeded before running the next function.) All of this is a *run-time* thing, though; it has nothing to do with compile-time code generation.

Comment: Can Haskell monads be as useful as Lisp macros to remove boilerplate code?

Comment: @mljrg If you are looking for Lisp macro equivalent in Haskell, then you have to go for Template Haskell. Monad and macro are two different things and comparing them is not proper.

Comment: @mljrg Surely that depends what you're trying to do. I'm no expert, but I would expect macros to be more powerful in principle. I can't comment on whether they're actually more useful in practice.

Comment: I feel like it's closer to compare lisp macros to haskell's laziness - you can sort of achieve lazy evaluation with quoted macros

Comment: @mljrg monads in general don't reduce boilerplate code, although some of them reduce nested case statements.

Answer (score 3):

If you can implement something with Lisp you can improve its syntax with a macro. Thus the macro part is just to make it look better or/and reduce code size.

You don't need macros to implement monads. Marijn Haverbeke has made a [monad implementation](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/monad.html) using `defstruct` and `defgeneic`.

Of course `defstruct` and `defgeneric` might use macros to implement it's magic, but it's not actually needed to implement monads. You can implement monads with closures. In the code below its used as a rudimentary OO with encapsulation and message passing.

```lisp
(defun maybe (val)
  (lambda (msg &optional f m)
    (case msg
      ((bind) (if val (funcall f val) m))
      (otherwise val))))

(defun bind (m f)
  (funcall m 'bind f m)) ;message passing

(defun value (m)
  (funcall m 'value))    ; message passig
```

Macros are functions that work on syntax. In a lazy language like Haskell macros can be replaced by functions since the arguments are evaluated only when needed. Eg. In CL,which has eager evaluation, you would need a macro to make your own `if` but you could do the same with a function in Haskell.

Comment: Closures are not “rudimentary OO”.

Comment: @Svante objects and closures over lexical scopes [serves the same purpose](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ClosuresAndObjectsAreEquivalent).

Comment: No.  They can be used for similar purposes.  You should not reduce one to the part that overlaps with the other.